# Getting setTimeout to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I have the following code which uses Jquery UI Drag and Drop. When the item is dropped into the area, the drop zone changes into the company logo, then I want a delay and a redirect to the URL within the dropped link.

I can get the logo to change OR the url to redirect but not both, when I have both setup the delay doesn't happen and the redirect goes start away. I assume I am doing something wrong with the setTimeout.

Code is as follows:

```
// let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
$( "#droparea" ).droppable({
  accept: "ul.gallery > li a",
  activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {

      var thelink = $(ui.draggable).attr("href");
      $('#droparea').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="../img/logo_navigation.jpg" />');

      setTimeout(redirectLink(url),5000);
  }
});

// URL REDIRECT FUNCTION
function redirectLink(url)
{
   window.location.replace(url);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Explanation

You need to pass a function reference (or a string of JavaScript code) to `setTimeout`, in order for it to be executed when the timeout is reached.

In your code, you were **immediately** calling the function (which doesn't `return` anything anyways, so its return value is `undefined`...so nothing will execute when the timeout is reached).

### Approach 1

Use an anonymous function that runs your code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    redirectLink(url);
}, 5000);

function redirectLink(url) {
   window.location.replace(url);
}
```

### Approach 2

Make your `redirectLink` function **return** a function and call it like you originally did:

```
setTimeout(redirectLink(url), 5000);

function redirectLink(url) {
    return function () {
        window.location.replace(url);
    };
}
```

### Approach 3

You could use `.bind()`:

```
setTimeout(redirectLink.bind(null, url), 5000);

function redirectLink(url) {
   window.location.replace(url);
}
```

Note that `.bind()` requires a polyfill for some older browsers.

---

References:

- `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout
- `Function.prototype.bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @pXL You didn't **return a function** like I did. Look: http://jsfiddle.net/pQGKv/2/

Comment: @bfavaretto I think they're trying to prove my second example doesn't work, but they didn't implement it correctly

Comment: @pXL No it shouldn't. That's not how `setTimeout` works. I've already pointed it out - the first parameter must be a string (of JavaScript to execute) or a function **reference**

Comment: @pXL Cool, glad you understand it now :)